Android status bar color property not applying for activities made from Empty Views Activity preset
It seems that for all of my activities which I made from the preset "Empty Views Activity" the property android:statusBarColor inside of themes.xml is just not applied. The status bar just defaults to a white background in light mode and black in dark mode, however inside of Android Studio's activity designer I see the correct status bar color. I am using the Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar parent for my theme.
Could this be because I need to apply something to the activity's XML code that is automatically applied when I make activities with other presets?

I managed to fix my own issue after a lot of research. It turns out that Activities which are created through the "Empty Views Activity" preset automatically get the line of code EdgeToEdge.enable(this); added to them. This enables Edge-to-edge for that Activity which causes the status bar to become transparent so that the Activity itself can draw stuff underneath it.
What I was experiencing was the Activity's background being drawn underneath the status bar, hence giving it a white background in light mode and a black background in dark mode.
Simply removing this line of code fixed my issue.
